# TypeError: Object.entries(...).flatMap is not a function at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have cloned a project from GitHub, node.js in my device is updated i.e, v14.16.1 but it is still giving the same error, I have tried uninstalling tailwind css and installing it again but it did not work either.
This is the url of the project repository [link](https://github.com/omamazainab/Apoyo-next)

[image]

this is the node version in my machine
[image]

Comment: Did you remove `node_modules` and then do `npm install` again after changing the Node.js version?

Comment: yes I tried deleting ```node_modules``` and ```package-lock.json``` and did ```npm install``` but I am getting same error

Comment: Could you provide the URL to the GitHub project you cloned? I'd suggest adding it to the question.

Comment: I have added the link to repository

Comment: The repo you linked has no reference to TailwindCSS. Are the changes in a branch?

Comment: I've successfully ran your project from the `dev` branch using Node.js 14. It must be an issue with the Node version on your machine. Are you certain you're using the right version? What's the output of running `node -v` in your terminal right before running `npm run dev`?

Comment: I have updated the question with the screenshot of `node --version`